# UITableViewCell - update cell after table has been drawn

Tags: ios, uitableview

I have a UITableView cell - I'm pulling info in from a network, and I have the following delegate method:

```
-(void)dataReturned:(NSString*)data indexPath:(NSIndexPath*)indexPath
{
        MyTableViewCell *currentCell = (MyTableViewCell*)[self tableView:self.tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];

        currentCell.someInfo.text = data;
        currentCell.smallActivityIndicator.hidden = YES;
}
```

but unfortunately neither "someInfo" nor the smallActivityIndicator seem to be updated.

Any suggestions as to what I'm doing wrong?

Thanks!

Comment: Did you try to call `-setNeedsDisplay` after hiding the activityIndicator? Is the `-dataReturned:indexPath:` method running on the main-thread or on a background-thread?

Comment: Just tried to call [currentCell setNeedsDisplay] / [self.tableView setNeedsDisplay] - neither worked + the method is running on the main thread.

Comment: Do you actually see a reference to an instance of MyTableViewCell in the debugger (perhaps by using `NSLog()`)?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Instead of getting the cell object and updating it, you could update your model with the new data and then call `reloadRowsAtIndexPaths:withRowAnimation:` ([reference](http://%E2%80%93%20reloadRowsAtIndexPaths%3awithRowAnimation%3a)). Reloading a row causes the table view to ask its data source for a new cell for that row. `cellForRowAtIndexPath:` will get called and it will construct a cell object from the model (which already has the new data).

Comment: This would be the recommended approach indeed, so I voted +1 - my suggestions are more of a workaround, but not the ideal way to go.

Answer (score 0):

Are currentCell, someInfo or smallActivityIndicator equal to nil?

Are you caching 'data' elsewhere or are you relying on MyTableViewCell to store your data?  You should probably be storing that string elsewhere.